# É possível exibir uma imagem diferente para cada tipo de Categoria no Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Possuo uma página em Wordpress com alguns posts, e os mesmos apresentam algumas categorias, mas vamos defini-las como: cat1, cat2 e cat3.

Dentro do `loop` do Wordpress são exibidos três `posts`, cada um com sua categoria e eles possuem uma imagem diferente para cada um, um exemplo disso é:

- Em `cat1`, os `posts` que possuírem essa categoria, terão uma imagem no canto escrito: 50% Off.
- Em `cat2`, os `posts` que possuírem essa categoria, terão uma imagem no canto, escrito: 70% Off.
- Em `cat3`, segue o mesmo critério...

Já possuo um código, e é ai que vem o meu grande problema, ele está repetitivo demais e isso me incomoda. Eu tenho um conjunto de três imagens com nomes e tamanhos diferentes.

Elas estão sendo chamadas dentro de vários `if`, segue exemplo:

```
$category = get_cat_name();
if ( $category == "cat1" ) {
   echo "<img src='...'> "
}
if ( $category == "cat2" ) {
   echo "<img src='...'> "
}
```

Há possibilidade de criar esse mesmo conteúdo sem uma enorme repetição?

---

**UPDATE:**
Tentei criar um `foreach`, mas acabei travando em como puxar as imagens de acordo com a categoria selecionada, o código ficou dessa forma:

```
$cat_name = get_cat_name();
$test = ["cat1", "cat2", "cat3"];
$images = ["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg"];

foreach ( $test as $t ) {
   if ( $cat_name == $t ) {
      $image = "<img src='./* Aqui que estou confuso */.'>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Você pode usar parâmetros dentro da sua condicional.

Comment: @durtto agora mesmo eu tentei um array de objetos e em seguida um foreach, mas acabei empacando em como chamar as imagens de forma ordenada (conforme categoria do foreach).

Comment: Não seria o caso de simplesmente renomear as imagens para o slug (nome curto) das categorias? Aí não tem nem foreach... Seria o caso de outra pergunta, mas dá pra colocar um field extra nas categorias,
 em site.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category

Answer (score 1):

Minha sugestão seria de usar **Switch** ao invés do **for..each**...

```
$categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID ); //pega categoria do post corrente
$cat_name = $category->slug; // pega o slug ao inves do nome da categoria pois esse pode ter espaços e acentos e vai dar problema no código
$image_tag = ""; // vai montar a tag de imagem com o valor correto

switch ( $cat_name ){ 
    case "cat1": $image = "img1.jpg"; break;
    case "cat2": $image = "img2.jpg"; break;
    case "cat3": $image = "img3.jpg"; break;
    default: $image = "placeholder.jpg"; break;
}

$image_tag = "<img src=./assets/images/". $image .">";
echo $image_tag;
```

Referência: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/